# UIImagePicker add Caption

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can't test this code in the iphone simulator but I was wondering if this is the best way to add a caption to a photo someone has taken in the UIImagepickercontroller class.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

_selectedImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UITextField *caption= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 60,640,200,40)];
    caption.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
   caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    caption.placeholder = @"Type Caption";
   [caption release];
}
```

Comment: Caption means ? Do u want to give a filename for the image and save it ?

Comment: [self.view addSubView: caption];

Comment: I'd like the person to take a photo, add a comment like "Taken at the beach" and then save.

Comment: where you want to add comment, over image?

Comment: preferably just under

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not make much sense for what you are trying to do, since it does not look like you are actually linking the caption to the image in any way.  I also do not know why you are releasing the text field - unless you turned Automatic Reference Counting off, that code should return an error.

What I would do (and did, to an extent, in a project of mine) is the following:

(1) Create some sort of object, like UserImg, which has two properties of type UIImage and NSString respectively.

(2) In the above function, when an image is selected, create a new UserImg and set the UIImage property to the select image.

(3) Display an UIAlertView with a text box and an okay and cancel button.  Use the text box to get the caption you want the user to save with the image.

(4) Set up a function to listen to the UIAlertView for okay and cancel button presses.  If the user cancels, remove the new UserImg.  If the user hits okay, copy the input text to the UserImg's NSString property.

(5) Profit?  I am not sure of the context of the image taking, so you'll have to figure out how you want to display things yourself.

You can test this functionality on the simulator as well.  You just need to set the code up so that it picks images from the device's image folder if no camera is present.  I forget exactly how to do this and do not currently have my source code on me.  I'll edit the answer later to include that if you cannot figure it out yourself in that time.

You will also have to add images to the simulator to choose from.  To do that, exit out of any apps running on the simulator (hit the home button, like you would on an actual device) and drag an image over on top of it.  When you do, in the top right corner, there should be an option to save the image to the device.

EDIT:

I noticed the comment you added about putting the caption below the image.  To do that, I would create a UserImgView which consisted of a UIImageView and a UILabel.  That way, when displaying the image using the custom view, you can display the UIImage in its ImageView and the caption right below it in the label.

Comment: You need UILabel not UITextField on top of the UIImage

Comment: Can you tell it's been a while since I looked at my code?  I did use a label in my actual code - editing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the flow I would take

- Let user select / take a picture
- Once user hits ok show a prompt to let them enter text.

[Sample Project 1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mscurrencyformatter)

[Sample Projects 2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uitext)

- Create a UIImageView and add their selected picture to it
- Create a UILabel and add it on top of the UIImageView
- Add their text to UILabel.

If you need to save the image with text on top of it then you need some sort of custom photo editor code or just take a screenshot and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create a NSDictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *photoCaptionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_selected.image,@"image",caption.text,@"caption",nil];
```

Whenever you want to show the picture you just do

```
[photoCaptionDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

and

```
[photoCaptionDict objectForKey:@"caption"];
```

shows the text.

Comment: Thanks and would the user be able to edit this caption once it appears?